# how to record audio and video in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, audio-recording, video-recording

I am new to gstreamer, I want to record both audio and video save it into .mp4 format, Recording video using webcam and audio using MIC

Here this is my pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! queue ! x264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! qtmux0. alsasrc ! 'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,depth=24' ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

When i am executing it the video is recording only for 10sec the audio not even recording, Its giving some message like

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:  
Can't record audio fast enough  
Additional debug info:  
gstaudiobasesrc.c(866): gst_audio_base_src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:  
Dropped 425565 samples. This is most likely because downstream can't keep up and is consuming samples too slowly.
```

Help me get over through this Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a "queue" before the "muxing":

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src ! queue ! x264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! qtmux0. alsasrc ! 'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,depth=24' ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, solved it by adding buffer-time=20000000 after the audio src ( alassrc in your case )

Here is an example that captures 640,480 desktop capture (Linux) and jack_out.monitor sound source:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc startx=0 starty=0 endx=639 endy=479 use-damage=0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=mux  ! queue ! filesink location=testAUDIOVIDEO2.mp4  pulsesrc device="jack_out.monitor" buffer-time=20000000 ! "audio/x-raw,channels=2,rate=48000" ! queue ! audioconvert ! queue ! opusenc bitrate=512000 ! queue ! mux. -e
```

Note the -e on the end of pipeline, this allows for sending EOS (End Of Stream) upon pressing CTRL-C.  Which will write all remaining buffers and create a playable file.